# copy all files of same type using eclipse external tools configuration

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, jboss

I want to create an external tools configuration in eclipse that will copy all .war files in my target directory to my deployments folder on jboss. My attempt looks like this:

[image]

but I get:

```
/bin/cp: cannot stat ‘*.war’: No such file or directory
```

When I give the actual name of the war file, it works but I don't want to use this approach as the name of the war file will change as the project gets updated. How can I use *.war or equivalent in this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expansion of '*' is done by the Shell not the program you run. So to do this you need to run the shell

For the command location specify:

```
/bin/sh
```

For the arguments:

```
-c "cp *.war /home/...."
```

which runs the shell specifying the command to be run.